# SELECT random records from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, random

I have 2 source tables employees, locations, which don't have the same record counts and a destination table access_history.

I want to randomly pick records (some columns from each table) and populate my destination table with those values.

I know I can do a subquery (see below) to populate the employee part of the access_history table.

```
INSERT into table access_history
SELECT 
from ( select employee_id, 
                     card_num 
                    from employees 
                    where 
                      last_name like '%' 
        order by dbms_random.value  ) 
      where rownum <= 2
```

I have 2 questions, how can I populate the locations part of the access_history table with random values.

Secondly, how can I populate access_date column with random but meaningful DATETIME values? Meaningful being a hierarchy of dates where the second date is greater than the first date by 10 minutes- 5 hours, the third date greater than the second date by the same criteria and so on and so for each record per random employee_id.

Lastly, this is ONLY test data and I'm not worried about performance issues as I know there is overhead with DBMS_RANDOM. My goal is to wrap this in a connect by level <= 10000 statement so I can generate plenty of test data.

Thanks in advance to all who answer.

My data should look something like this:

```
SELECT * from access_history 
ORDER BY employee_id, access_date 

1, 'AAA1', 101,  '06212020 21:02:04', 0
1, 'AAA1', 102,  '06212020 21:22:54', 0
1, 'AAA1', 104,  06222020 01:13:11', 0
1, 'AAA1', 101,  '06212020 05:29:22', 0

3, 'CCC3', 105,  '06212020 08:42:34',0,
3 'CCC3', 102,  '06212020 16:09:55', 0
3 'CCC3', 104,  '06212020 22:29:53', 0


CREATE TABLE employees
(
   employee_id NUMBER(6),
   first_name VARCHAR2(20),
   last_name VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
   card_num varchar2(10)  NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE employees
     ADD ( CONSTRAINT employee_id_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (employee_id));


Insert into employees values (1, 'Mike', 'Jones', 'AAA1');

Insert into employees values (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', 'BBB2');


Insert into employees values (3, 'Paul', 'Smith', 'CCC3');

Insert into employees values (4, 'John', 'Henry', 'DDD4');



 Create table locations(
   location_id NUMBER(4),
   location_name varchar2(30),
   location_type char(1));

 -- A=access T=Time & Attendance 

ALTER TABLE locations 
     ADD ( CONSTRAINT lication_id_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (location_id));



Insert into locations values (101, 'South Front Door 1', 'T');

  Insert into locations values (102, 'South Front Door 2', 'T');

  Insert into locations values (103, 'East Back Door 1', 'T');

   Insert into locations values (104, 'East Back Door 2', 'T');

   Insert into locations values (105,'Computer Room', 'A');

   Insert into locations values (106,'1st Floor North',  'A');


Create table access_history(
   employee_id NUMBER(6), 
   card_num varchar2(10),
   location_id number(4),
   access_date date,
   processed NUMBER(1) default 0
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably clean SQL solution is possible, but I would make PLSQL block with two simple loops. It is much cleaner, you can see what's going on, easy to modify:

<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d94adf9470a9c12ca1ad2e45476f83b6)</sup>

```
declare
  v_loc number;
  v_dt date;
begin
  -- take two random employees
  for emp in (select employee_id, card_num 
              from (select employee_id, card_num 
                    from employees order by dbms_random.value ) 
              where rownum <= 2) loop

    -- set starting date
    v_dt := timestamp '2020-06-21 08:00:00';

    -- for each employee generate 3 to 5 rows
    for i in 1..dbms_random.value(3, 5) loop

      -- get random location
      select location_id 
        into v_loc 
        from (select location_id from locations order by dbms_random.value) 
        where rownum = 1;

        -- increase last used date by random 10 to 300 minutes
        v_dt := v_dt + dbms_random.value(10, 300)/(24*60);

        insert into access_history (employee_id, card_num, location_id, access_date)
        values (emp.employee_id, emp.card_num, v_loc, v_dt);

    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Sure. I hardcoded starting date as something similiar to yours, but for each row it is increased by random value. Also two employees. You can make these date and number of employees as procedure parameters or use sysdate or random values. Just change this code block into procedure with parameters and use them instead of `2` and given date.